# How to use GFS to store data in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

We are currently running spark jobs, store the data in HDFS and create Hive tables on top of it. Now, we are planning to migrate from HDFS to GFS to store the Hadoop data. Is it possible to use GFS as our Hadoop File System in our case, either by mounting or CIFS share or using GFS directly?

The following link talks about remote mounting of devices, but it mentions that it is not specific to any of the details.

https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/other/reference-architecture/topics/ra_storage_device_accepta...

Please refer me to any document that explains in detail about remote mounting of devices.